# Is there an android equivalent of iOS alphanumeric index overlay control?

Tags: android, scroll

On some lists, e.g., in the phone contacts, there is a control overlaid which allows you to jump to a section using an alphanumeric index.  (I'm not sure what the canonical name for that is but it's referred to as an index in some of the questions about it here.)  Does an equivalent control exist in Android?  Ideally it would work under API 8, but I'm targeting 17 and I'm happy to just turn it off for older devices.

If there isn't a built in one, a library that can be used in commercial products would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [IndexScroller](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexScroller.java) if you are looking for something like this:

[image]

If you are looking for an example on how to use it, please check [IndexableListView](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/blob/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget/IndexableListView.java)

Comment: That's the sort of thing I'm looking for, yes, thank you!  Is there also an example of how to use it?

Comment: @whysohard I have included a sample link. Please mark the question as aswered.